# @Output childEvent not initialized in component

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to set output value in component . write this code for output :

```
export class OutputComponentComponent implements OnInit {

      @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();

      @HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
      onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
         this.functinoOutput();
      }
        
     private functinoOutput() {
       this.childEvent.emit('value')
     }
}
```

and i use this component in `appcomponent.html`

```
<app-ouput (childEvent)="showCordinate($event)"></app-ouput>
```

but it show me this error :

> Error: @Output childEvent not initialized in 'ResizableComponentComponent'.

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Comment: make sure that EventEmitter is imported from @angular/core and what is the ResizableComponentComponent? here is OutputComponentComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not import `EventEmitter` in your TS file or import that one from wrong library. If not then try the code given below.

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

If you are using `import { EventEmitter } from 'events';` then please replace your import with my one. 
**NOTE:** If you still facing problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to declare a flag?

```
export class OutputComponentComponent implements OnInit {
      initialized = false;
      @Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();
  @HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
     if (this.inizialited) {
          this.functinoOutput();
     }
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.inizialited = true;
}   

 private functinoOutput() {
   this.childEvent.emit('value')
 }
}
```

Optional: try to declare better the @Output

```
@Output() search: EventEmitter<ClassOrSomething> = new EventEmitter(false);
```